# How to ask for the size of array in Angular2 using interpolation?

Tags: angular

How can I ask about the size of an array in angular 2 when I am using it in a component, for example:

```
users : User[];
```

with

```
export class User {
  id : number;
  firstName : String;
  lastName  : String;
  userName  : String
}
```

and

```
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
      <th scope="row">{{ user.id }}</th>
      <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.userName }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

what should be the way to ask for the size on array inside a *ngIf expression using interpolation to detect it the size is different to empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tbody *ngIf="users.length">
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
      <th scope="row">{{ user.id }}</th>
      <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.userName }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thanks! it worked ok, one more question: how do you do make evaluations like "length equal to 3" o "length is different to 2"?

Comment: the *ngIf wait a result of a conditionnal comparaison. So you can reuse the same syntax to evaluate other state like `users.length  == 3` or `users.length != 2` and display/hidden other html block.